# In shell,Get a maximum value among all rows of a column and compare it to each row

Tags: bash, shell

I need to get a highest value among all rows of a particular column(C2) and save the value in variable ,Lets say "max'. then compare max variable value with each row , If the row value is greater than or equal to max the column3(c3) should print passed, if the row value is lesser than max value the C3 should print failed. I wrote below code but its giving me passed for all. What wrong in my script?

```
cat /tmp/test.csv
awk 'BEGIN{ max=0 } {if(($2).max) max=($2)}END {print $1,$2,max}' /tmp/test.csv
cat /tmp/test.csv
awk -F '' 'BEGIN{ OFS=";"; print "sep=;\nPackages;count;maxValue;Validation;'};
{if($2 >= $3)
print $1,$2,$3,"passed"
else
print $1,$2,$3,"failed";}'/tmp/test.csv

my csv file looks:
Vmname   Packages   count   
-----------------
Vm1      a,b,c,d     4
vm2      a,b,c       3
vm3      a,b         2


my expected output is:
   vmname    Packages   count   maxValue  Validation 
    --------------------------------------
    vm1       a,b,c,d     4       4        passed
    vm2       a,b,c       3       4        failed
    vm3       a,b         2       4        failed
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I have added sample input and expected csv file .Please check

Comment: @anubhava packages names are seperated by comma

Comment: @anubhava Both are in different columns...My input file is csv

Comment: @anubhava    its semicolon ;

Comment: Did you forget to mention it anywhere in your question? That might be the reason below answer are not working for you.

Comment: So should I  use semicolon instead of comma in this line ??  print $0;max;max==num?"Passed":"Failed"    ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution since OP mentioned Input_file, its slightly changed from previous one only.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if(FNR==1 || FNR==2){ next }
  num=split($0,aray,",")
  max=max>num?max:num
  next
}
FNR==1{
  print $0,"maximum Validation"
  next
}
FNR==2{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($0,array,",")
}
{
  print $0,max,max==num?"Passed":"Failed"
}
'  Input_file  Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                         ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  if(FNR==1 || FNR==2){ next }                ##Checking if line is 1st or 2nd line then simple skip that line.
  num=split($0,aray,",")                      ##Splitting current line into array named aray with delimiter comma here. Where num will be total nuber of elements in array here.
  max=max>num?max:num                         ##Checking if max is greater than num then keep max value or assign num value to max.
  next                                        ##next will skip all further statements from here onwards.
}
FNR==1{                                       ##Checking condition if FNR==1 its first line then do following.
  print $0,"maximum Validation"               ##Printing current line with maximum and Validation sting here in very first line of Input_file.
  next                                        ##next will skip all further statements from here onwards.
}
FNR==2{                                       ##Checking condition if FNR==2 then do following.
  print                                       ##Printing current line here.
  next                                        ##next will skip all further statements from here onwards.
}
{
  num=split($0,array,",")                     ##Splitting current line into array with delimiter comma and total number of array will be stored into variable num here.
}
{
  print $0,max,max==num?"Passed":"Failed"     ##Printing current line then max and printing passed or failed as per condition here.
}
'  Input_file  Input_file | column -t         ##Mentioning Input_file names here and sending awk program output to column command to arrange it better.
```

---

---

Could you please try following, where I am considering that your Input_file is as follows:

```
cat Input_file
Packages
-------
a,b,c,d
a,b,c
a,b
```

then following is the solution:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if(FNR==1 || FNR==2){ next }
  num=split($0,aray,",")
  max=max>num?max:num
  next
}
FNR==1{
  print $0,"count maximum Validation"
  next
}
FNR==2{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($0,array,",")
}
{
  print $0,num,max,max==num?"Passed":"Failed"
}
'  Input_file Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: Is it array in line 4 ?

Comment: and also I have added my input file in question.Please check

Comment: @Stella, no worries it will work, there is no typo :)

Comment: @Stella, please check it and let me know it worked with Input_file which I mentioned in my answer, kindly do let me know how it goes.

Comment: I will check.. One more doubt. In My csv first column is somthing else which is not my concern and second column has packages, third column has count of packages. Can I go ahead with the the same code u have give..or any changes required?

Comment: @Stella, no it assumes that your entire line has only `a,b,c,d` like stuff if not then you need to change solution a bit change $0 to `$2` in case its 2nd column or so etc. Better to update your actual Input-file once in your post.

Comment: I have updated my question .Am chaning $0 to $2 amd trying..Will post the output in a moment

Comment: @Stella, was having dinner :) could you please check my EDIT one and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

Edited for new input.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ max=0; i=0; }
     $3+0 > 0 { row[i]=$0; num[i++]=$3; if($3>max){max=$3} }
     END {
       printf "\t%s\n", "vmName   Packages   count   maxValue  Validation\n\t --------------------------------------"
       for (p=0;p<i;p++) { if (num[p]<max) {msg="failed"} else {msg="passed"}
         printf "\t %-25.25s    %d  \t%s\n", row[p],max,msg; } }' test.csv
```

This reads through the file once to load the input and sets the `max` as it goes, prints the header at the end, then loops the arrays of input to set the pass/fail string for each.

Questions welcome.

Output -

```
    vmName   Packages   count   maxValue  Validation
     --------------------------------------
     Vm1      a,b,c,d     4       4         passed
     vm2      a,b,c       3       4         failed
     vm3      a,b         2       4         failed
```

Comment: If the difference in spacing matters we can refine it similar to the way I set the field width of the first column, instead of using tabs. As an aside, is the number column in the input needed, or *could* we just count the subfields of the first column?