# In awk, Divide values in to array and count then compare

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have a csv file in which column-2 has certain values with delimiter of "," and some values in column-3 with delimiter "|". Now I need to count the values in both columns and compare them. If both are equal, column-4 should print passed, if not is should print failed. I have written below awk script but not getting what I expected

```
cat /tmp/test.csv
awk -F '' 'BEGIN{ OFS=";"; print "sep=;\nresource;Required_packages;Installed_packages;Validation;"};
{
column=split($2,aray,",")
columns=split($3,aray,"|")
Count=${#column[@]}
Counts=${#column[@]}
if( Counts == Count)
print $1,$2,$3,"passed"
else
print $1,$2,$3,"failed";}'/tmp/test.csv
```

[![my csv][1]][1]
my csv file looks:

```
resource   Required_Packages   Installed_packages  
--------------------------------------------------
Vm1         a,b,c,d               a|b|c     
vm2         a,b,c,d               b|a
vm3         a,b,c,d               c|b|a
```

my expected file:

```
resource   Required_packages   Installed_packages      Validation  
------------------------------------------------------------------
Vm1         a,b,c,d               a|b|c                Failed
vm2         a,b,c,d               b|a                  Failed
vm3         a,b,c,d               c|b|a|d              Passed
```

Comment: Typo: `split($2.aray,",")` should be `split($2,aray,",")`

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variable `aray` for both splits.

Comment: You can't use `${#column[@]}` in in awk, that's shell syntax.

Comment: `column` and `columns` are already the counts. You should use `if (column == columns)`

Comment: `alidation;'};` you closed quoting `'` there, you meant to use `"`

Comment: Why do you have `-F ''`? What is the field separator in the input file?

Comment: That's not a CSV file.

Comment: @Barmar tried already no help

Comment: @Stella Tried what? There are so many problems in your script that need to be fixed.

Comment: That's an awk script, not a shell script, and you're trying to use shell constructs in it. awk and she; are 2 completely different tools, each with their own language. You can't use shell constructs in an awk script any more than you could use them in a C program. So - your input file isn't a CSV file and your program isn't a shell script. Using `-F ''` in an awk script invokes undefined behavior per POSIX btw so YMMV with what that'll do using any given awk but none of the possibilities are useful for your posted input file.

Comment: I see in [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62877536/1745001) you said in the question `my csv file looks:` then showed something that was not a CSV file and looks similar to what's in this current question and then in the comments you said that your separator was actually a semi-colon. When providing sample input/output, just post what the files contain, don't post some other visual representation as we need something concrete to test with and compare your code to.

Comment: So - please post the **actual** contents of your "CSV" file and your **actual** expected output (i.e. the exact files as they'd exist in your filesystem) so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code doesn't match the input/output data (where are the dashed printed, etc) but
this code segment

```
column=split($2,aray,",")
columns=split($3,aray,"|")
Count=${#column[@]}
Counts=${#column[@]}
if( Counts == Count)
print $1,$2,$3,"passed"
else
print $1,$2,$3,"failed";
```

can be replaced with

```
print $1,$2,$3,(split($2,a,",")==split($3,a,"|")?"Passed":"Failed")
```

Also, just checking the counts may not be enough, I think you should be checking the matches as well.

Comment: It may not be necessary to check for matches if installed packages is always a subset of required packages.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that's right mathematically but not sure a valid assumption in practice.

Comment: Column-3 will not be in same order as coulmn-2.. Still ur script works?

Comment: order doesn't matter for count checks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR<=2{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($2,array1,",")
  num1=split($3,array2,"|")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     value[array1[i]]
  }
  for(k=1;k<=num1;k++){
     if(array2[k] in value){ count++ }
  }
  if(count==num){ $(NF+1)="Passed" }
  else          { $(NF+1)="Failed" }
  count=num=num1=""
  delete value
}
1
'  Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR<=2{                                   ##Checking condition if line number is lesser or equal to 2 then do following.
  print                                   ##Printing current line here.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  num=split($2,array1,",")                ##Splitting 2nd field into array named array1 with field separator of comma and num will have total number of elements of array1 in it.
  num1=split($3,array2,"|")               ##Splitting 3rd field into array named array2 with field separator of comma and num1 will have total number of elements of array2 in it.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                    ##Starting a for loop from 1 to till value of num here.
     value[array1[i]]                     ##Creating value which has key as value of array1 who has key as variable i in it.
  }
  for(k=1;k<=num1;k++){                   ##Starting a for loop from from 1 to till value of num1 here.
     if(array2[k] in value){ count++ }    ##Checking condition if array2 with index k is present in value then increase variable of count here.
  }
  if(count==num){ $(NF+1)="Passed" }      ##Checking condition if count equal to num then adding Passed to new last column of current line.
  else          { $(NF+1)="Failed" }      ##Else adding Failed into nw last field of current line.
  count=num=num1=""                       ##Nullify variables count, num and num1 here.
  delete value
}
1                                         ##1 will print current line.
'  Input_file | column -t                 ##Mentioning Input_file and passing its output to column command here.
```